# Very basic volume rendering using OpenGL functions (for teaching purposes)

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I have some students doing a project on volume rendering. I am trying to devise the most basic possible example to get them started.  What I want to do is have a window and set each pixel in the window independently, based on raycasts through the underlying volume dataset. This could easily be done with Windows API functions, for example.  But we want to use OpenGL.

Two ideas I've had:

1. Use glut to create a window.
2. Manually set each pixel in the window using some OpenGL function.

Or, slightly more complex...

1. Use glut to create a window.
2. Create an off-screen texture the same size as the window.
3. Set each pixel individually in the texture, based on the results of raycasting.
4. Flip the texture to the window contents.

So my question is twofold: is there a better method than these options? and can someone point me to the relevant OpenGL functions to accomplish these methods?

Comment: I think using OpenGL just for plotting single pixels is a waste. In a University course on Volume rendering we used the *OpenGL Shading Language* GLSL to do the ray casting.

Take a look at VJo's post he has good links.

Comment: I agree that using some hardware accelerated GPU based volume rendering would be sweet.  However, some students really are not up to that, and the ones that are don't need my help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option, pixel by pixel will be *really* slow! I would suggest you to create a RGB buffer with the same size as the window and use [glDrawPixels](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml) to draw it.

EDIT:

```
unsigned char * buffer = new unsigned char [width * height * 3];
glRasterPos(0,0);
glDrawPixels(width,height,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,buffer);
delete [] buffer;
```

Comment: Any quick hint you can give me on how to create a RGB buffer and flip it to/from the window?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into one of these ray casting examples, and pick one that suits your need :
http://www.daimi.au.dk/~trier/?page_id=98
http://cumbia.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/ger/research/fields/current/spvolren/

Comment: LOL - from my title "*Very basic* volume rendering".  GPU based volume rendering is waay out of the scope of this project.

Comment: @Dave Ok, sorry. I am not aware of anything simpler :(

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way of using opengl for volume rendering is creating a 3D texture and draw a set of transparent planes that are perpendicular to your viewing direction and slicing through your 3D volume texture map.

by applying blending on the slices, you can see the volume.